# Cloudflare and Domain Validation SSL

Tags: nginx, meteor, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I managed to get a Comodo Domain Validation SSL and install into my box with NGINX for a Meteor app running. When visiting the site directly, I see the correct certificate. However, when I enable Cloudflare + Universal SSL + then choose Full (Strict), I still see a Cloudflare issued certificate. Is this supposed to happen, or am I supposed to see my own certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is as expected. Cloudflare uses your certificate between your nginx server and Cloudflare.

Between Cloudflare and the client's browser a cloudflare certificate is used.

If you disable strict mode you can use a self signed certificate. If you use Flexible SSL you don't need a certificate on your server.

In all 3 cases the browser will see Cloudflare issued certificates.